# How can I set DOCKER_HOST environment variable?

Tags: docker, maven

**docker** is installed and the service is active.
But when I run a Maven build I get the error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.27.2:stop (stop-staled) on project egisso-db: Execution stop-staled of goal io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.27.2:stop failed: No <dockerHost> given, no DOCKER_HOST environment variable, no read/writable '/var/run/docker.sock' or '//./pipe/docker_engine' and no external provider like Docker machine configured -> [Help 1]
```

I've read some discussions where some people suggest values for this variable like `tcp://...` but I don't know where I can find its exact value.

I thought that `docker info` would give some information, but no:

```
sudo docker info|grep tcp
```

Not sure whether its important, but I have to start the **service** using `sudo`, but I can use the docker as **client** as normal user.

Answer (score 3):

you can set the environment variable via `export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://HOST:2375"`

see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#examples

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/#environment-variables